# Add button to trigger script along top bar in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the script below to hid all rows that have a specific box checked. I set a trigger using the clock and every 10 minutes but instead seems to run every time I check a box and it screws up the view every time I check it. I would like to change it to a manual trigger that is a button along the top bar that someone manually clicks. Can anyone help me edit it?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2 Week Snapshot');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('C:C')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 1) 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [I'-'I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i), the name given to your function causes your script to run when an edit is made to the sheet. From the Apps Script documentation on [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/):

> To use a simple trigger, simply create a function that uses one of these reserved function names:
>    - `onOpen(e)` runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, presentation, or form that the user has permission to edit.
>    - **`onEdit(e)` runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.**
>    - `onInstall(e)` runs when a user installs an add-on.
>    - `doGet(e)` runs when a user visits a web app or a program sends an HTTP GET request to a web app.
>    - `doPost(e)` runs when a program sends an HTTP POST request to a web app.
>   
> The `e` parameter in the function names above is an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that is passed to the function. The object contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire, but using it is optional.

Renaming your function to avoid binding this simple trigger will prevent edits of your sheet from triggering your function.

Documentation to look at:

- [Guide to Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Guide to Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have modified the script a lot but have a new issue posted above.

Comment: @I'-'I I have modified it back and although your answer does fix part of the problem it did not actually answer my question.

Comment: @Leilani This documentation will show you how to add a menu to your spreadsheet.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: @New_2_Code Thank you for your very helpful feedback. I figured it out after lots of beating my keys on the keyboard. As |'-'| instructed I have posted a new question with the buttons all figured out. If you can assist that would be nice... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282357/how-to-merge-scripts-so-one-stops-undoing-the-other]

Comment: @tehhowch Good idea, added links to the answer.