# How to merge scripts so one stops undoing the other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the script below to hid all rows that have a specific box checked or if a different cell has the word "Newer". The problem I am running into is that when I run the hideReviewed_ function it undoes the hidden rows done by the second function hideNewer_. How do I blend these 2 so that I can run 1 function and it will look and both and hid the both the checked boxes and the items that say "Newer"?

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Reviewed', functionName: 'hideReviewed_'},
    {name: 'Newer', functionName: 'hideNewer_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Hiding Time', menuItems);
}

function hideReviewed_() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2 Week Snapshot');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('C:C')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 1) 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}

function hideNewer_(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2 Week Snapshot');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('J:J')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'Newer') 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    function hideReviewed() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
  s.getRange('C:J').getValues().forEach(function (r, i) {if (r[0] == 1 || r[7] == "Newer") s.hideRows(i + 1)});
}
```

Changes that were made:

- I get the entire range C:J
- In the if statement I check to see if r[0] is equal to 1 OR if r[7] is equal to "Newer".

r[0] is Column C
r[7] is Column J

Tested this in a sample spreadsheet and seems to be working as intended.
Hope this helps.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]